# For a given integer Z, check if Z can be written as P^Q where Q and P are positive integers

Tags: php, math, exponential

Here is what I have tried but it is giving me wrong output. Can anyone point out what is the mistake?

```
function superPower($n) {
    $response = false;
    $n = abs($n);
    if ($n < 2) { 
       $response = true;
    }
    for ($i=2;$i<$n;$i++) {    
        for ($j=2;$j<$n;$j++) {
            if (pow($i,$j) == $n) {
                $response = true;
            }
        }
    }  

    return $response;   
}
```

For example if I give it number 25, it gives 1 as output. //Correct
But if I give it 26 it still gives me 1 which is wrong.

Comment: I see argument named `$Z` , but not assigned to `$n`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Perhaps using logarithms might speed things along

Comment: By the way, too many iterations. Maximum `$i` shall be `sqrt($n)`, Maximum `$j` shall be `ln($n)/ln($i)` (such that i^j >= n)

Comment: if ($n<2) $ret=true; isnt that suppose to be $response?

Comment: How are you checking the results? I've just tried the function (no modifications, just as it is defined in the question) and I'm getting the following results: `25 -> true`, `26 -> false`… so everything seems to be working.

Comment: It does not work. Always return 1 for any number

Comment: Maybe if `$i`and `$j` values become too big, there might be a chance for an integer overflow (and therefore spurious results if`pow($i,$j)` was trimmed back to integer)?

Comment: Yes may be that overflow is happening. Also I wrote 0 instead of false. Its kinda strange but replacing false with 0 seems to work. Thanks everyone.

Comment: and you should break out of the loop once response is set to true for better performance

Comment: Why go into the loop after the if statement if you have decided the response is `true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using superPower, you are essentially trying to put a certain defence to the power of an attack to see if it holds up. This can be done much more effectively than through the brute-force method you have now.

```
function superPower( $hp) { // Niet used Superpower!
    if( $hp <= 1) return true;

    for( $def = floor(sqrt($hp)); $def > 1; $def--) { // Niet's Defence fell
        for( $atk = ceil(log($hp)/log($def)); $atk > 1; $atk--) { // Niet's Attack fell
            if( pow($def,$atk) == $hp) return true;
            break;
            // you don't need the $atk loop, but I wanted to make a Pokémon joke. Sorry.
        }
        // in fact, all you really need here is:
        // $atk = log($hp)/log($def);
        // if( $atk-floor($atk) == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! This is much better way.

Comment: You might want to guard against an invalid input to the function!

Answer (score 2):

The maths on the accepted answer is absolutely brilliant, however there are a couple of issues with the solution:

- the function erroneously returns `true` for all of the following inputs: `monkey`, `-3` and `0`. (Technically `0` is unsigned, so there is no way of getting it by taking a positive integer to the power of another positive integer. The same goes for any negative input.)
- the function compares floating numbers with integers (`floor()` and `ceil()` return `float`), which should be avoided like the plague. To see why, try running `php -r '$n = (-(4.42-5))/0.29; echo "n == {$n}\n".($n == 2 ? "OK" : "Surprise")."\n";'`

The following solution improves on the idea by fixing all of the above issues:

```
function superPower($value)
{
    // Fail if supplied value is not numeric
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        // throw new InvalidArgumentException("Value is not numeric: $value");
        return false;
    }

    // Normalise numeric input
    $number = abs($value);

    // Fail if supplied number is not an integer
    if (!is_int($number)) {
        // throw new InvalidArgumentException("Number is not an integer: $number");
        return false;
    }

    // Exit early if possible
    if ($number == 1) {
        // 1 to the power of any positive integer is one
        return true;
    } elseif ($number < 1) {
        // X to the power of Y is never less then 1, if X & Y are greater then 0
        return false;
    }

    // Determine the highest logarithm base and work backwards from it
    for ($base = (int) sqrt($number); $base > 1; $base--) {
        $coefficient = log($number)/log($base);

        // Check that the result of division is a whole number
        if (ctype_digit((string) $coefficient)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that the error handling is not present in the function provided in the OP, so @Niet just mimics the original behaviour. And if you want to throw an exception because of invalid input, you should throw an [```InvalidArgumentException```](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php).

Comment: @Arjan That is true, error handling is missing in the OPs function, however the question does clear stipulates the condition under which the function should work: "For a given integer Z…". As for the exception, I'll update the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, I'm inclined to disagree with avoiding `ceil/floor <=> int` comparisons "like the plague". As a general, yes, floating point imprecision means that comparing to an int is a bad idea. However in this case, `ceil/floor` return an integer (that happens to be in float form to reduce the risk of clipping a 51-bit mantissa to a 32-bit int) and is therefore precise (barring extremely high numbers that ints can't represent anyway)